# sprintf - what does it actually do

Tags: c, printf

this is part of my code

```
int pic_num = 1;
printf("pic_num = %i\n", pic_num);
sprintf(picture, "%03d.jpg", pic_num);
printf("%s, pic_num = %i\n", picture, pic_num);'
```

first value of pic_num is 1, but second value, after sprintf is 6778986
Why?
What does sprintf actually do? I thought it just make a string picture = 001.jpg
But what about pic_num? Why does it change a value?

Thank you

You all were wright. It should be [8] or [16]. Thank you all.

Comment: How did you declare `picture`? (should be at least `char[8]`).

Comment: Show us the declaration of `picture`. You are probably overflowing it.

Comment: Show the whole code, and show the whole output.

Comment: Wild guess: The `picture` array is declared above the `pic_num` variable, hence located in the stack before that variable (it really depends on the compiler, but that's what probably happens in your case). This array is not large enough to accommodate those 7 characters + a null character (i.e., 8 characters in total). So when `sprintf` writes `001.jpg` into the `picture` array, it overrides the `pic_num` variable which is located after it in memory.

Comment: The only thing `sprintf` actually does is suck the life out of developers.

Answer (score 9):

The value `6778986` gives `0x0067706A` in hexadecimal, which correspond to the last 3 ASCII characters and the null terminator (`"jpg"`) of what should have been in the `picture` string.

This indicates that you defined `picture` just before `pic_num`, and only 4 bytes large. I'm guessing you defined it as :

```
char picture[4];
```

You need to properly size the string to hold at least 8 characters (but potentially more depending on how large the `pic_num` value can get), so what gets written into it by `sprintf` doesn't overflow into `pic_num`. For example :

```
char picture[16];
```

For more info on what `sprintf` does, refer to this reference eg. : http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Answer (score 3):

[sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) writes the results to a character string buffer. So it is like printf but instead of printing to `stdout` it stores result in a buffer

```
int sprintf( char* buffer, const char* format, ... );
```

The size of the buffer should be large enough to contain the entire resulting string which is characters + terminating null at the end. You can use a `snprintf` as a safer version.

You have got 6778986 because this resulted from taking p[ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values of characters "jpg" (with terminating '\0'), the `0x0067706A'

```
'\0' 'g' 'p' 'j'
0x00  67  70  6A
```

what tells us that most probably your `picture` is incorrectly declared as

```
char picture[4];
```

and thus has not enough space for 8 characters string "%03d.jpg" (+ '\0').

You should declare buffer as

```
char picture[8]; // space for at least 7 characters + '\0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `sprintf` is similar to function `printf` except that it outputs formated data in a character array instead of the standard stream `stdout` as `printf` does.

I think that the problem is that you did not allocate enough memory for variable `picture` to store the result string after the call of sprintf. So the program overwrites memory occupied by pic_num.

If you will try the following code

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() 
{
    int pic_num = 1;
    std::printf( "pic_num = %i\n", pic_num );
    char picture[8];
    std::sprintf( picture, "%03d.jpg", pic_num );
    std::printf( "%s, pic_num = %i\n", picture, pic_num );

    return 0;
}
```

you will get the expected result

```
pic_num = 1
001.jpg, pic_num = 1
```